# How to authenticate the user from the email?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, email, authentication, devise

I have a rails application which uses devise for authentication. when the application sends any notification to the user, then in order to see the notification or messages i provide a link to my rails application which redirects to a login page.

how can i avoid this login process, means i don't want the user to be asked to login by entering email and password, instead whenever the user clicks on that link, then the user should automatically login.

Comment: Bear in mind there are serious security implications for what you are intending - anybody who has the link can log in as the user. Since the request is a GET request it will be saved in the browsers history. Say that the user is using a public computer at a library and signs out of the application - another person using the computer can hit the back button and be signed into your application using the users credentials.

Comment: You could use tokens - but make sure they are single use. A better solution may be to setup Devise to redirect back after sign-in.  https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Redirect-back-to-current-page-after-sign-in,-sign-out,-sign-up,-update#a-simpler-solution

Comment: By tokens i mean single use tokens that let you view a resource without authentication - not token based authentication that would actually log the user in.

Answer (score 0):

Devise provides `sign_in` controller helper which allows you to pass authentication programmatically.

```
sign_in(user)
```

Comment: Because it gives the OP just enough rope to hang himself with. It answers the question - but is it a good answer? No.

Comment: @max feel free to provide a better answer

Comment: To a six year old low effort question? Nah, hard pass.